# Please recommend a document parsing tool for vb.net and asp.net based application.

Tags: open-source, web-development, document-management, visual-studio

I am developing a recruitment portal with VB.net and asp.net application.

In this application we are using a document parsing tool called Burning Glass Technologies Lens tm. The primary goal of Lens tm engine is to manipulate and process documents specifically resumes and job posting in the recruitment portal.

**For example :** Normally the system can filter any name / address/ phone number / key skill or any other information by using SQL query as long as the information are exist in the database according to proper order. But the database query can not filter inside the uploaded documents/ file (in this case the candidates CV uploaded in the system as a document or pdf file format). To enable user to search for a key word not only from the database but also from uploaded files we are using Lens tm engine.

**Some Basic details about what Burning Glass is:**
Burning Glass Lens tm server consists of several process with different functionality. These process communicates with each other using CORBA (Common Object Request Broker Architecture http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/corbafaq.htm).

There are three types of functionality provided by the system. Registering Document, parsing documents and scoring documents.

Registering Document enables user to find matches between resumes and job posting. parsing document is to enable user to parse a document. Scoring documents provides an advanced search capability based on the score it calculate between two documents.
Below is the web link of the company.
http://www.burning-glass.com/solutions-for/job-boards/

---

I apologize for including so much details about Burning Glass (I have only included these details to help you understand what we are using now and our requirement).

The Burning Glass is an excellent tool for the document parsing and filtering. There is one major problem about this tool is it is astonishingly expensive (many thousands GBP per year). We are a small company and the license fee has become an issue now. For this reason we are looking for an alternative document parsing and filtering tool.

We will be very grateful if anyone can suggest an open source or a comparatively cheaper document parsing and filtering tool which we can implement in our ASP.net and VB.net based web application.

I apologize if the question is not appropriate for this forum.

We appreciate your help.

Thank you